# Postgresql using Trigger to update column values after inserting values

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to insert the values into a tableA and then update the column[amount_hkd].
I have successfully use the trigger but the performance is really slow, it takes an hour to finish the insertion of 8400 rows after I apply the trigger.
How can I improve the performance?
Thanks for your help

The statement to exectue:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (suppliers, invoice_dates, shipment_dates, amounts, currency, currency_conversion_rate)
SELECT l.supplier, l.invoice_date, l.shipment_date, l.amount, l.currency, o.currency_conversion_rate
FROM tableB l
LEFT JOIN tableC o
ON l.currency = o.currency_code
WHERE l.supplier = 'ABC'
```

The function I created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cal() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN 
UPDATE tableA 
SET amount_hkd = NEW.amounts * NEW.currency_conversion_rate;
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The 1st Trigger I tried:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER update_amount
AFTER INSERT ON tableA
DEFERRABLE
INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE cal();
```

The 2nd Trigger I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_amount 
AFTER INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE cal();
```

Comment: You need a `BEFORE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW`

Comment: Your trigger updates _all_ rows with the same value for `amount_hkd` every time you insert one. That's why it is slow. Is this what you really need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is terribly inefficient to update the row after you inserted it. Better is to use a `BEFORE` trigger that can modify the new row *before* it is inserted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cal() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN 
   NEW.amount_hkd := NEW.amounts * NEW.currency_conversion_rate;
   RETURN NEW; 
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_amount 
   BEFORE INSERT ON tableA FOR EACH ROW 
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE cal();
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify your Postgres version, but if at least V12 you can avoid triggers altogether. Define the column `amount_hkd` as a generated column. Not only do you avoid triggers, but you also eliminate maintenance issues of updating the  `currency_conversion_rate` and/or `amount` and forgetting to also update `amount_hkd`, or a direct update to `amount_hkd`. Something like: ( see [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9d915c930bb7badc9169b2bf460b8534))

```
create table table_a( a_id integer generated always as identity 
                    , amounts  decimal
                    , currency_conversion_rate decimal
                    , amount_hkd decimal generated always as ( amounts * currency_conversion_rate ) stored
                    );
```